# Queries are faster in SSMS 2008R2 as compared to SSMS 2016

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am connecting to a database server(MSSQL 2008R2) using SSMS 2016 and for simple queries even like "USE DBNAME", it's taking 4-5 secs. However time stat shows "CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms", not sure why?

On the other hand, If I connect the same server using SSMS 2008R2, it gets executed instantly.

I compared client statistics for both SSMS2008R2 AND 2016 but both shows almost same stats.

Why my SSMS2016 is behaving like this?

Comment: Are you using [the latest SSMS 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) ? Also, what is the value of `UserFeedbackOptIn` 1 or 0 ?

Comment: I checked again and it's latest SSMS 2016.

Comment: UserFeedbackOptIn is 1. Will it impact in anyway?

Comment: I have changed it for SSMS 2016 .. look for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\UserFeedbackOptIn`

Comment: I changed UserFeedbackOptIn setting in registry, but still no help.

Comment: Also changed the same setting at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Setup\UserFeedbackOptIn".

Comment: Just removed Apex add ons from SSMS 2016 and now it looks better. 
But still slow in comparison to SSMS 2008R2. Just a diff of half sec around.

Comment: May be UserFeedbackOptIn setting also helped, I think. Thanks @Kin

Comment: You did not mention that you had Apex Addin .. that would be my first choice to disable. Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the below setting and uninstalling some add ons for SSMS 2016 helped me -

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\UserFeedbackOptIn

Thanks @Kin.